# Which rxjs operator should i use for the following condition?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code which runs an inner observable if the outer observable give valid value..

1. Here the first observable which is the outer observable is a behaviorSubject. This behavior subjects initial value is null. Upon user login the behaviorSubject give us a user object.
2. The second observable which is the inner observable is a http call which will totally depend on the user object. So it will only run if the outer observable give us a useful user object instead of null.
3. And at the end i want to subscribe to the inner observable..

Right now i don't to know which operator should i use so i am using subscription inside of subscription..Here my code

```
item = [];
ngOnInit(){
 this.service.outerObs.subscribe(user => {
  if(user !== null) {
   this.http.get('some route', {headers: new HttpHeader({"Authorization": user.token})})  //here i am using the user object
    .subscriber(result => {
       this.items = result;
     })
  }
 })
}
```

If i first login and then visit this component i won't have any issue because my behaviorSubject will have the last user object. But if i already in this component and try to reload my app than i am getting issue because my autoLogin funcion takes some time to set the user object in behaviorSubject.So i have to check if the behaviorSubject has a useful user object instead of null before sending the http call...
Which rxjs operator should i use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest 2 changes

1. Instead of `BehaviorSubject` with default `null`, you could use `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1. It behaves the same way as `BehaviorSubject` except you don't have to deal with default value `null`.
2. You could use higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to switch from outer observable to the HTTP call.

Try the following

**Service**

```js
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  private outerObsSrc = new ReplaySubject<any>(1); // <-- hold and emit last value on subscription
  public outerObs = this.outerObsSrc.asObservable();
  
  ...
}
```

**Component**

```js
item = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.outerObs.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (isValidUserCheck) { // <-- check if the `user` variable is a valid user
        return this.http.get('some route', {headers: new HttpHeader({"Authorization": user.token})});
      }
      return of(null); // <-- return `null` if `user` is invalid
    })
  ).subscribe(
    result => {
      if (!!result) { // <-- check if `result` is defined
        this.items = result
      }
    },
    err => {
      // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
    }
  );
}
```

#### Update: `subscribe` overload being deprecated

As mentioned by @LarsVanderheydt [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64404519/which-rxjs-operator-should-i-use-for-the-following-condition/64404829#comment113885715_64404829), subscription overload sending callbacks directly as used in the original answer is being deprecated. Instead you could send in an object containing the callbacks.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.outerObs.pipe(
    ...
  ).subscribe({
    next: (result) => {
      if (!!result) { // <-- check if `result` is defined
        this.items = result
      }
    },
    error: (err) => {
      // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you could also use the filter operator if you're not doing anything with the results (sidenote, passing 2 separate methods in subscribe will soon be deprecated. So get used to passing an object with next and error ({ next: () => {}, error: () => {}})

Comment: @LarsVanderheydt: That's a good point about the subscription callback deprecation. I've updated the answer. Thanks :)